# Save Selenium results in a file

Tags: selenium, csv

I try to save my web scraping results in a csv file by using openpyxl

If I print my results with the following command, I am able to see al the data necessary:

```
i = 1
g = len(titles)
while i < g:
  print(titles[i].text)
  print('\n')
  print(sections[i].text)
  print('\n')
#  print(dates[i].text)
#  print('\n')
  i += 1
```

but if I try to save the results with the following comamand to csv file:

```
for r in range(1,5):
    for c in range(1,4):
        sheet.cell(row=r,column=c).titles[i].text
        
workbook.save(path1)
```

I do get the follwing error message:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-487-201b34800c46> in <module>
      1 for r in range(1,5):
      2     for c in range(1,4):
----> 3         sheet.cell(row=r,column=c).titles[i].text
      4 
      5 workbook.save(path1)

AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'titles'
```

As I am a total beginner, it would be great to get an explanation what is wrong... Thanks!

Comment: looks like you're working with a spreadsheet, not csv...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error, you'll see it says `'Cell' object has no attribute 'titles'`. That means that you're looking for titles in the wrong place, and in your example with printing, you just have titles as a list. This sort of seems like a makeshift solution, so I'd recommend using a data-frame with something like pandas, as it's easy and intuitive to work with in python and has simple exporting. Also, it's a little hard to troubleshoot, as this isn't a minimum workable example. That means I can't see the type of the variables, or data in them.

Answer (score 0):

Is it simply this line:

```
sheet.cell(row=r,column=c).titles[i].text
```

Should be an assignment?

```
sheet.cell(row=r,column=c) = titles[i].text
```